String Field Conversion to Time
I have a string field with date values and I want to convert this field in Time type.
The values are as this: "9:31:00 a.m."
I write:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE proyecto.dataset.nueva_tabla AS
SELECT
TIME(PARSE_TIME('%I:%M:%S %p', hora_gest)) AS hora_gest
FROM proyecto.dataset.tabla_original;

This error was generated cause Big Query sentence:
PARSE_TIME('%I:%M:%S %p', hora_gest)
don't understand "9:31:00 a.m." but the format valid to conversion is "9:31:00 am". Thus, first I deleted with points with subtrings "a.m." and "p.m."
